# TCPView (Windows) doesn't show any addresses

Tags: windows-10, tcp, sysinternals, network-traffic, traffic-filtering

I'm using TCPView 4.16 for Windows 10 (downloaded from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview). Up until a few days ago it worked fine, but all of a sudden it simply stopped showing addresses, and instead showing either `::` or `::1`. Here's how it looks like:

[image: screenshot of TCPView]

I've searched online but resources on people with this same problem are sparse and with no resolution. Running as administrator or not makes no difference, issue still happens in either case. I've tried purging every entry of TCPView from the registry (it doesn't install so I can't uninstall it), redownloading, I've tried using an older version (4.0), and the problem is still there - I simply can't get it working again.

As added info, after a PC reboot it does show the addresses immediately after I first open it for about 3-4 seconds, then it defaults back to showing `::` or `::1` . Moreover, when using a similar app like CurrPorts, that one shows the addresses just fine - so i suppose it's not something wrong with my system, but with TCPView specifically.

I would drop using it altogether, but I find the filtering and UX a lot better/more friendly in TCPView so I'd like to be able to keep using it somehow. Has this happened to anyone else, and/or does anyone know what i could try to fix this?

Comment: Try completely removing TCP View.  I had V3.05 and just upgraded to V3.16 and Local IP addresses show fine: 64-bit, 32-bit, standard user, admin user.

Comment: Should say 4.16 above. Typo on my part.

Comment: How do i remove it completely? 4.16 doesn't come with an installer

Comment: Remove the entire folder, restart, download it again and put in a new folder. See if that works. I put 4.16 on Windows 10 Pro , Windows 11 Pro Insider, and Windows 11 Pro Production and it worked fine on all 3 machines.

Comment: I did that numerous times, and with several versions, while also removing all entries found with RegEdit. No change.

Comment: Are you sure there *is* anything to be shown when you open the app? What your screenshot shows is fairly normal "listening" sockets and localhost connections (::1 is indeed an address, the "localhost" IPv6 address, and :: is the "listen on any" address) but are there actually any other connections that are supposed to be shown alongside those?

Comment: Well if i filter by the chrome process is still looks the same. There were definitely addresses there before

Answer (score 0):

TCP View and other networking tools use Windows built in networking.

When that fails to work for all applications, the best and usually fastest / easiest correction is a Windows Repair Install.

For Windows 10:

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.
>
> Begin with the first option to Keep Everything. There are more
> aggressive options if that fails. It should work however.

In this case, as in many, a Repair Install is a good, sturdy repair that leaves your system as it was when you started the Repair.

Comment: Right, but as i mentioned, it doesn't fail for all applications because:
1) it still works every time for about 3-4 seconds right after a reboot
2) CurrPorts works perfectly all the time.

Moreover, tcpvcon (which is in the same package as TCPView) also works just fine, as well as netstat

Comment: Given your last post, I still think a Repair Install is a good thing (easy, 3 or 4 steps and watch the paint dry) to make a good correction.